# Dynamic delegation inheritance

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have constructor functions `Foo`, `Bar` and `Qux`. How can I create a new object with a delegation chain (using those constructors) that I would dynamically choose on the fly ?

For example, an object would have the delegation chain `Foo` -> `Bar`.
Another object would have the chain `Foo` -> `Qux`.

```
function Foo() {
  this.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
  }
}

function Bar() {
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

function Qux() {
  this.qux = function() {
    console.log('qux');
  }
}
```

An object `fooBar` would be able to call `foo()` and `bar()`. Another object `fooQux` would be able to call `foo()` and `qux()`. Etc.

Comment: + for saying delegation instead of inheritance. You should also populate the constructor's prototypes i suppose.

Comment: Sorry a little confused. What is it that you would like to do?

Comment: When do you want to establish the chain link? When creating a new instance using the constructor? How would a `fooBar` object be created?

Comment: How exactly would the object call the function, what is the constructor, and how specifically would a delegation chain look in javascript ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand question correctly, but I guess we can try to use `instanceof`? [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/m4v11931/)

Comment: @Neal actually I try to have dynamic decorators, where for one object I can choose which are its decorators. I think Bergi has a nice solution for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use those constructors as mixins:

```
var fooBar = {};
Bar.call(fooBar);
Foo.call(fooBar);

var fooQux = {};
Qux.call(fooQux);
Foo.call(fooQux);
```

But you might want to write them as decorators, maybe even returning the modified object, not as constructors, because you cannot use their prototypes anyway. So a more convenient pattern would be

```
function withFoo(obj) {
  obj.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
  };
  return obj;
}

function withBar(obj) {
  obj.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
  };
  return obj;
}

function withQux(obj) {
  obj.qux = function() {
    console.log('qux');
  };
  return obj;
}
```

so that you can use them like

```
var fooBar = withFoo(withBar({}));
var fooQux = withFoo(withQux({}));
```

Comment: That would let you do `fooBar.bar()`, not sure if that's what the OP means by *"...have the delegation chain `Foo` -> `Bar`"*, seems rather unclear to me ?

Comment: @adeneo You're right, it's not entirely clear, so I mostly ignored it. It doesn't seem to be about prototype delegation as far as I can tell. But `Foo` (the "outer" mixin) can refer to the methods of `Bar`/`Qux` (the "inner" mixins) which already exist on the object.

Comment: "An object `fooBar` would be able to call `foo()` and `bar()`" sounds an awful lot like mixins.

Comment: @Bergi decorators is exactly what I want, so you simple create a function that will add methods to your object. It's simple and I didn't think about it (I was trying to make it work with prototype delegation and couldn't achieve it)

Comment: @Bergi I don't understand the solution with .call(). How do I use it?

Comment: @Matthew [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is for the constructors you've shown in your question, it just invokes them so that `this` refers to the object that they should add their methods to.

Comment: @Matthew regarding prototypes, while you cannot dynamically delegate properties to multiple prototype objects, you can use decorators on a prototype as well as long as it doesn't need to initialise per-instance state.

Comment: @Bergi I have some troubles: https://jsfiddle.net/zf92gvfp/8/ would you mind having a look?

Comment: @Matthew The mixin looks fine. If you by "troubles" you mean the `NaN`, that comes from initialising `.value` with `undefined`. Use `new Foo(0)` instead.

Comment: @Bergi In your answer, you say it's likely better to go for decorators (second snippet). Because with my constructors => "you cannot use their prototypes anyway". Can you explain for a JS novice this reasoning?

Comment: @Matthew You cannot dynamically add multiple prototypes to inherit from to a single object, the prototype chain is linear (not a tree). You cannot have `Foo.prototype` inherit from `Bar.prototype` in one setting and from `Qux.prototype` in another.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, not sure but I guess you can try `instanceof`.

Idea is, have a wrapper function that will check for constructor and will call necessary function. An alternative could be having same name function in all class function. So you just have to call `object.functionName()`

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/m4v11931/1/)

```js
function Foo() {
  this.foo = function() {
    console.log('foo');
  }
}

function Bar() {
  this.bar = function() {
    console.log('bar');
  }
}

function Qux() {
  this.qux = function() {
    console.log('qux');
  }
}

function createObj() {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 3;
  switch (index) {
    case 0: return new Foo();
    case 1: return new Bar();
    case 2: return new Qux();
  }
}

function checkObjectAndCallFunc(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof Foo) {
    delete obj;
    obj.foo();
  } else if (obj instanceof Bar) {
    delete obj;
    obj.bar();
  } else if (obj instanceof Qux) {
    delete obj;
    obj.qux();
  }
}

function test(obj) {
  obj = createObj();
  checkObjectAndCallFunc(obj);
  if (count < 10) initTimeout()
}
var count = 0;
var obj = {};

function initTimeout() {
  count++;
  setTimeout(test.bind(null, obj), 1000);
}
initTimeout()
```